# Extract rows from table when columns is no empty in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select rows when  field "**beruf_1**" is not zero.

beruf_1 is type VARCHAR

These four entries write me error.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE != '0' ";
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE != 0 ";
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE > 0 ";
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE > 'a' ";
```

*Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxx.php on line 141*

Another:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE '!= 0' ";
```

*Result = 0*

this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE '%a%' ";
```

*Result all rows, when field **beruf_1** contains "**a**"*

and this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 LIKE '%' ";
```

*Result all list* - No matter whether empty or with the entry

Can you help me?

Comment: your `like` is **COMPLETELY** wrong. the syntax is `where somefield LIKE 'somevalue'`. you cannot `like` a  comparison operator. `like !=` is utterly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but only this entries working:

      `$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE length(beruf_1) > '0' ";`

or

     `$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE length(beruf_1) > 0 ";`

Comment: `length()` returns an integer. comparing it to a string (`'0'`) is pointless. and `'!= 0'` is also wrong. `'` starts a string, so your `!=` isn't the "not equals" operator, it's just two characters in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple check in where condition will work for you.

```
SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 != 0
```

As far error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxxx.php on line 141` concerned, you are getting this due to wrong `sql`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a check of not equal so you don't need the LIKE function.  Since it's a type VarChar you would want to have quotes around it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 != '0' ";
```

Example

```
members [table]
|  ID  |  beruf_1  |
|  1   |     0     |
|  2   |     12    |
|  3   |     10    |
|  4   |     0     |
|  5   |     01    |
```

This should return

```
|  ID  |  beruf_1  |
|  2   |     12    |
|  3   |     10    |
|  5   |     01    |
```

Comment: Result all from list. :(

Comment: This should return everything from the list where beruf_1 is not a string 0.  Can you show what your table and entries look like?

Comment: Thanks, but only this entries working:
 `$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE length(beruf_1) > '0' ";`
or `$sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE length(beruf_1) > 0 ";`

Comment: those queries will only compare the length of the string.  Example:  Length("0") == length("1") ... because they are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from members WHERE beruf_1 <> '0'
```

The operator different in SQL language is `<>`

for more information you can see this link [SQL operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)